# C# .NET Website - adding a CSS class to menu elements

Tags: c#, .net, css, menu, master-pages

I've been using PHP for 7 years or so now, but as of today I've been thrust into using .NET for a project. Just for an insite:

This project features:

.NET4
Viewstate = false

Now my issue is this. The main layout is covered by the master page which seems quiet obvious how it works. It also includes nav menu options such as:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="default.aspx" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.aspx" title="Products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="prices.aspx" title="Size &amp; Price">Size &amp; Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="formats.aspx" title="File Formats">File Formats</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Now what I would like to do would be to add a CSS class attribute depending on what page I'm on so if I was on the products page I'd get the following source:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="default.aspx" title="Home" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.aspx" class="active" title="Products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="prices.aspx" title="Size &amp; Price">Size &amp; Price</a></li>
        <li><a href="formats.aspx" title="File Formats">File Formats</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, one way is to add a script to the "slave" page that sets the class of the appropriate  tag.

```
<li><a href="default.aspx" title="Home" id="aHome" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="products.aspx" title="Products" id="aProducts">Products</a></li>
```

Then in products.aspx you can do:

```
<SCRIPT>document.getElementById('aProducts').setAttribute('class', 'active');</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Thats a great solution thank you. I never even thought of a Javascript solution as I normally try to avoid them but that does what I need perfectly, although I'd prefer to have it hardcoded to do so this will work fine. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, all three answers would work.  The plus side of the others is that all the magic happens on the server side, they don't rely on client-side scripting.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to your question, but this was in the CSS category so I figured I'd at least comment :)

I would strongly suggest that you set static classes on each list item, and combined with body classes in the CSS, use something like:

```
<style type="text/css"><!--
    body.products #menu li.products a,
    body.otherpage1 #menu li.otherpage1 a,
    body.otherpage2 #menu li.otherpage2 a,
    body.otherpage3 #menu li.otherpage3 a,
    body.otherpage4 #menu li.otherpage4 a, { /* your styles here*/ }
--></style>
```

I think that using C# in order to *just* set a class is a little overkill, that's all :)

Comment: Yes this is good actually I've used this approach and in the "slave" page that uses the masterpage I add another style and selector for just the item I want to look different.  It effectively "overrides" the prior style.

Comment: @mikey Yes, exactly. As long as the overriding style is after the initial style, there's no use for !important, which is an abomination in it's own right :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by converting the links to server controls.  See [the MSDN page for <asp:HyperLink />](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx).  From there, I'd make an interface for my MasterPage, so that if I ever need to change MasterPages in the future, I can implement the same interface and not have to worry about breaking my build (we'll publicly expose some properties in the next step, so this will be useful).

```
public interface IMasterPage
{
    String LnkHomeClass { get; set; }
    String LnkProductsClass { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Now as I mentioned, expose the CssClass attribute for your HyperLinks in the code-behind of your MasterPage.

```
public string LnkProductsClass
{
    get 
    {
        return LnkProducts.CssClass;    
    }
    set
    {
        LnkProducts.CssClass = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can set these on your child pages.

```
IMasterPage masterPage = Master as IMasterPage;
if (masterPage != null)
{
    masterPage.LnkProductsClass = “active”;
}
```

Another option, but one that I am less familiar with, may be to use [nested MasterPages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2b3ktt7.aspx).